# Custom Push Segue show the tab bar

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a problem with the tab bar controller. On one of the views that is linked from the tab bar controller (view1), there is a custom segue that leads to another view (view2).

Help me to unhide the tab bar which get hidden due to the custom segue.

Comment: What is your VC heirarchy?

Comment: Please show piece of code or screen :)

Comment: i am noob so far i understood when i used push segue the tab bar is shown but when used custom or modal segue it doesn't show the tab bar at bottom

Answer (score 0):

The navigation bar and the tool bar should disappear in the storyboard when you change the segue -- that's normal. You can change the simulated metrics for the bottom bar to "Translucent Toolbar", which will add it back, so you can add buttons to it (you only want to change the simulated metrics, not drag in another tool bar which would add a second tool bar). You should still see both bars with their buttons at run time.

[Refer url...](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/tutorial/ios-5-creating-a-custom-side-tabbar-using-storyboards-and-custom-segues/)